# how to make a dynamic scrollable checkboxlisttile by vertical and horizontal?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

How to make UI like this?
[image: Expected UI]

The checkbox data list is dynamically generated using Column children List.generate().
and the problem is when the data text name is overflowed like this. and I want to make it scrolled to horizontal not per item list. when scrolled to horizontal all of data get scrolled too.
[image: Attempted implementation of the UI]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qhse_auto/common_ui/button/OutlineButtonTextOnly.dart';
import 'package:qhse_auto/common_ui/button/PrimaryButtonTextOnly.dart';
import 'package:qhse_auto/common_ui/empty_padding.dart';
import 'package:qhse_auto/common_ui/widgets/common_search_filter.dart';
import 'package:qhse_auto/common_ui/widgets/common_textfield.dart';

class PopupSelectUserWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopupSelectUserWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<PopupSelectUserWidget> createState() => _PopupSelectUserWidgetState();
}

class _PopupSelectUserWidgetState extends State<PopupSelectUserWidget> {
  bool isCheck = false;
  final List<int> shades = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];
  final ScrollController _horizontal = ScrollController(),
      _vertical = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 20, right: 24, bottom: 16),
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const CommonTextField(
                    hint: 'Search NIK, Nama, Departemen, Jabatan',
                  ),
                  12.ph,
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 12,
                      right: 12,
                      top: 12,
                      bottom: 12,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: const Color(0XFF7F8895).withOpacity(0.30),
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Anggota Team',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Divider(
                          color: Color(0XFFE1E1E1),
                          thickness: 1.5,
                        ),
                        12.ph,
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height / 2.5,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Scrollbar(
                            controller: _vertical,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              controller: _vertical,
                              child: Scrollbar(
                                controller: _horizontal,
                                thumbVisibility: true,
                                trackVisibility: true,
                                notificationPredicate: (notif) =>
                                    notif.depth == 1,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  controller: _horizontal,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: List.generate(40, (index) {
                                      return CheckboxListTile(
                                        value: isCheck,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isCheck = value!;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        title: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            const CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/images/ilham.jpeg'),
                                            ),
                                            4.pw,
                                            RichText(
                                              text: const TextSpan(
                                                text: 'Ristu Aji W',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                                children: [
                                                  TextSpan(
                                                    text: '\n19786',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Color(0XFF7F8895),
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w500,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            24.pw,
                                            RichText(
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              text: const TextSpan(
                                                text: 'Operation',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                                children: [
                                                  TextSpan(
                                                    text:
                                                        '\nMobile Developersdsdsdsdsdsds',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Color(0XFF7F8895),
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w500,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: OutlineButtonText(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            label: 'Cancel',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 16),
                        Expanded(
                          child: PrimaryButtonTextOnly(
                            onTap: () {
                              // goNext(context);
                            },
                            label: 'Next',
                            isActive: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i expected the data can be scrolled together to horizontal and vertical

Comment: yes i do, but it overflowed on title

Answer (score 0):

I checked your can given code there are some steps are to be focused. you need to wrapping the row of CheckboxListTile widgets inside a SingleChildScrollView with a horizontal scroll controller. Here's how you can do it:

1. Remove the outer SingleChildScrollView widget.
2. Wrap the row of CheckboxListTile widgets inside a
   SingleChildScrollView with a horizontal scroll controller.
3. Add a ScrollController for horizontal scrolling and pass it to the
   SingleChildScrollView.

I think this code snippet works for you.

```
child: Scrollbar(
                      controller: _horizontal, // Add horizontal scroll controller
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: _horizontal, // Pass the controller to SingleChildScrollView
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // Set horizontal scrolling
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: List.generate(40, (index) {
                              return CheckboxListTile(
```